# How can i hide/show my navigation bar (Not navigation controller) when tapped on view?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have one navigation bar in my scroll view.(Use StoryBoard)
I want to hide my navigation bar when user tap on view.
When user tap again, the navigation bar will show.
How can i make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a navigation bar (without a controller), you have to animate the changing of the frame of the navigation bar, as well as that of the scroll view. In the example below, I'm just shifting the navigation bar off the top of the screen and adjusting the size of the scroll view accordingly. You obviously need `IBOutlet` references for both the navigation bar as well as the scroll view:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) BOOL navigationBarHidden;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationBarHidden = NO;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}

- (void)handleTap:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect navBarFrame = self.navBar.frame;
                         CGRect scrollViewFrame = self.scrollView.frame;

                         if (self.navigationBarHidden)
                         {
                             navBarFrame.origin.y += navBarFrame.size.height;
                             scrollViewFrame.size.height -= navBarFrame.size.height;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             navBarFrame.origin.y -= navBarFrame.size.height;
                             scrollViewFrame.size.height += navBarFrame.size.height;
                         }

                         self.scrollView.frame = scrollViewFrame;
                         self.navBar.frame = navBarFrame;

                         self.navigationBarHidden = !self.navigationBarHidden;
                     }];
}
@end
```

If you're using autolayout, it's slightly different (you have to animate the changing of the constraints), but the basic idea would be the same. Let me know if you're targeting iOS 6 and higher only and are using autolayout.

---

If you're using a navigation controller, it's a little easier, as you can hide with [`setNavigationBarHidden`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW9):

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

You can show with:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

If you want to do this on a tap, you can do something like (you'll need an `IBOutlet` to your scroll view for this):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}

- (void)handleTap:(id)sender
{
    BOOL hidden = self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden;

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!hidden animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: your help is very useful for me. I value your help. Your answer make me more easy to develop. Thanks you very much.